# UDID in iOS 7.0 beta version

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7

Currently my app in the appstore has the UDID feature in it and customers have downloaded the version of the app with UDID feature in it. But I have done the new changes for identifiers with vendorID. But what happens to the App which has already been downloaded by my customers with the UDID in it. Like how will the UDID get generated in iOS 7.0 beta if UDID is being accessed in it. Can someone help me with this ?

Answer (score 2):

I understand you're talking about beta features.  For this reason, please consider removing this question, and moving it to the apple developer forum where you won't be violating NDA.

In general terms, for identifier transitions, you should consider how you're currently using identifiers, and create a transition plan which associates any old identifiers with newer identifiers you may use in the future.

Apple also has some discussion in the docs about things like persistence and use of the new identifiers, so I would encourage you to use those resources, and post in the developer forums until iOS 7 is public.

Answer (score 2):

UDID and all related methods are deprecated in iOS7. You can use

`NSUUID *deviceUUID = [[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor];`

instead. This is the proposed way of Apple.

Comment: so, what if the user deletes the  app and installs again... it will change... what is unique then ?

Answer (score 1):

Since UDID is deprecated in the iOS 7 beta, which is out now for download. The users of your application will definitely observe a crash when the app will try to fetch the UDID using UIDevice class.

Until Apple releases a iOS7 (stable version, which is not very far from now), you should update your current app with a message for iOS7_beta users (with conditional coding for iOS7_beta and update your app in appstore). This will not put your current app users dislike your app, and will stick to your even after release of iOS7 hoping to get amazing features for your app.

Hope it helps!